# Série de taylor para cos(x) - em C

Tags: c, matemática

Tenho tentado calcular esse somatório, porém estou com problemas para fazer o fatorial dar certo...
alguem pode me ajudar a identificar meu erro?

.
[image: formula]

Onde x é o ângulo em radianos e N a quantidade de termos da série menos 1.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
    double x, z = 0, fat = 1;
    int n, i, j, fat2=0;
    scanf("%lf%d", &x, &n);

    j = 1;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        //printf("\n%d :: %lf :: %d ", fat2, fat, i); // DEBUG

        z = z + ( ( pow(-1 , i)*pow(x, (2*i)) ) / (fat) ); 

        fat2 = 2*j;
        fat = fat * (fat2 - i);

        j++;
    }
        printf("\ncos(x) = %lf\n", z);  

    return 0;
}
```

edit:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
    double x, z = 0.0;
    int n, i, j;
    scanf("%lf%d", &x, &n);
    double fat[n], fat2[n];

    fat[1] = 1.0;
    for(j = 1; j < n; j++){
        fat2[j] = 2.0 *i;
        fat[j] = fat[j] * (fat2[j] - j); 
        printf("\n%lf\t%lf", fat[j], fat2[j]);

    }

    fat[0] = 1.0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        //printf("\n%d :: %lf :: %d ", fat2, fat, i); // DEBUG

        z = z + ( ( pow(-1 , i)*pow(x, (2*i)) ) / (fat[i]) ); 

    }

        printf("\n\ncos(x) = %lf\n", z);    

    return 0;
}
```

---

Edit 2 [resolvido]:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/*long int fatorial(int n){
    long int fat = n * (n - 1);
    if(n == 0 || fat == 0)
        fat = 1.0;

    return fat;}*/

long fat(int n) {
    if(n < 2)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * fat(n-1);    //return (n < 2) ? 1 : n * fat(n-1); 
    }


int main()
{
    double x, z = 0.0;
    int n, i, j;
    scanf("%lf%d", &x, &n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        z = z + ( ( pow(-1.0 , i)*pow(x, (2.0*i)) ) / (fat(2*i)) ); 
        //printf("\n\t%ld", fat(2*i)); //debug
    }

        printf("\n\ncos(x) = %lf\n", z );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: qual é o problema ?

Comment: Preciso retornar o valor do somatória da foto acima, porém na hora de calcular o fatorial de (2 * n) da errado, pois tem aquele conceito de 0! é igual a 1... E ai bagunça um pouco, já tentei colocar um if pra essa condição mais continua dando valores errados para os fatoriais seguintes

Comment: (1) crie uma funçãozinha à parte para calcular fatorial(n); crie uma tabela (array) à parte, e inicialize nesta tabela os valores 0!, 2!, etc... (2) em cada iteração do comando for você pega o próximo elemento desta tabela de fatoriais

Comment: Faz como o @zentrunix lhe disse, crie uma função fatorial.

Comment: Criei um array... Porem só retorna 0.0...

Comment: Não entendi seu cálculo de fat[j], me parece que você não está calculando o fatorial corretamente. Utilize uma função do tipo: long fat(int n) {
 return (n < 2) ? 1 : n * fat(n-1);
}
e chame com fat(2*i). Depois que seu programa estiver correto mas você achar que pode otimizar então otimize.

Comment: Opa, entendi agora... N tinha pensado dessa maneira... Tentei fazer a funçao do fatorial da maneira q coloquei em parenteses no edit 2... Porém retornava 0.000000... Enfim, a todos, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O OP já resolveu sua dúvida, mas para registro, aqui vai uma versão otimizada, que calcula o fatorial sem recursividade e sem repetir operações. Ainda dá para melhorar um  pouquinho nas contas, por exemplo calcular "2*i" apenas uma vez...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

static long fat = 1; // fat(2*0)

int main()
{
  int n, i, j;
  double x, z = 0.0;

  scanf("%lf%d", &x, &n);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++ )
  {
    printf("* i=%d fat(%d)=%d\n", i, 2*i, fat);
    z = z + ( ( pow(-1.0 , i)*pow(x, (2.0*i)) ) / fat );
    fat = fat * (2*i+1) * (2*i+2); // proximo fat
  }

  printf("\n\ncos(x) = %lf\n", z );

  return 0;
}
```

Teste:

```
[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./377309
3 5
* i=0 fat(0)=1
* i=1 fat(2)=2
* i=2 fat(4)=24
* i=3 fat(6)=720
* i=4 fat(8)=40320

cos(x) = -0.974777

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$
```

Conferindo aqui [nesta pagina](https://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/Factorial.html) parece que o cálculo do fatorial está certo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela contribuição!